# Icono asociado a un tipo de archivo en Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Tengo el siguiente código para obtener el icono asociado a un tipo de archivo, implementado para **Windows**:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)

#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtWinExtras/QtWin>

QIcon IconFromFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    QIcon qIcon;
    HICON hIcon;

    hIcon = ExtractIconW(NULL, (const WCHAR*)fileName.constData(), 0);
    if(hIcon == NULL)
    {
        SHFILEINFO shfi;
        DWORD dwFileAttributes;

        memset(&shfi, 0, sizeof(shfi));
        if(QFileInfo(fileName).isDir())
            dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        else
            dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE;

        SHGetFileInfoW((const WCHAR*)fileName.constData(),
                       dwFileAttributes,
                       &shfi,
                       sizeof(SHFILEINFO),
                       SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON);

        hIcon = shfi.hIcon;
    }
    if(hIcon != NULL)
    {
#if (QT_VERSION_MAJOR == 4)
        qIcon = QIcon(QPixmap::fromWinHICON(hIcon));
#else
        qIcon = QtWin::fromHICON(hIcon);
#endif
        DestroyIcon(hIcon);
    }
    return qIcon;
}
#elif defined(Q_OS_LINUX)

QIcon IconFromFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    // TODO: Implementar en Linux
    return QIcon();
}

#endif
```

Me gustaría si alguno me pudiera dar sugerencias de como obtener el icono asociado a un tipo de archivo en **Linux**, estoy usando **Linux Mint**.

Comment: Cual es la versión concreta de Qt?

Comment: Ahora estoy usando Qt5, pero el código que subí lo implementé cuando usaba Qt4.
Pero ahora con Qt5, vi que provee la clase QFileIconProvider(), lo probé en Windows y me funciona, pero todavia no lo probé en Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente encontré una solución a mi problema, independiente del sistema operativo, utilizando la clase QFileIconProvider que provee Qt a partir de la versión 5.2.
También me fué útil el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617981/how-to-get-qt-icon-qicon-given-a-file-extension).

Mi código final es el siguiente:

```
#include <QIcon>
#include <QString>

#if ((QT_VERSION_MAJOR > 5) || (QT_VERSION_MAJOR == 5 && QT_VERSION_MINOR >= 2))

#include <QFileIconProvider>

QIcon IconFromFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    return QFileIconProvider().icon(QFileInfo(fileName));
}

#else

#include <QPixmap>
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
#include <windows.h>

#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtWinExtras/QtWin>

QIcon IconFromFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    QIcon qIcon;
    HICON hIcon;

    hIcon = ExtractIconW(NULL, (const WCHAR*)fileName.constData(), 0);
    if(hIcon == NULL)
    {
        SHFILEINFO shfi;
        DWORD dwFileAttributes;

        memset(&shfi, 0, sizeof(shfi));
        if(QFileInfo(fileName).isDir())
            dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        else
            dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE;

        SHGetFileInfoW((const WCHAR*)fileName.constData(),
                       dwFileAttributes,
                       &shfi,
                       sizeof(SHFILEINFO),
                       SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON);

        hIcon = shfi.hIcon;
    }
    if(hIcon != NULL)
    {
#if (QT_VERSION_MAJOR == 4)
        qIcon = QIcon(QPixmap::fromWinHICON(hIcon));
#else
        qIcon = QtWin::fromHICON(hIcon);
#endif
        DestroyIcon(hIcon);
    }
    return qIcon;
}
#elif defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QMimeDatabase>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QFileInfo>

QIcon IconFromFile(const QString& fileName)
{
    QMimeDatabase db;
    QIcon icon;
    QList<QMimeType> types = db.mimeTypesForFileName(fileName);
    for(int i = 0; i < types.count(); i++)
    {
        icon = QIcon::fromTheme(types[i].iconName());
        if(!icon.isNull())
            return icon;
    }
    if(QFileInfo(fileName).isDir())
        return QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirIcon);
    return QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_FileIcon);
}

#endif

#endif
```

Saludos! Espero que a otros le sirva mi solución.